# Daily Coding Challenge solution - day 21

Tags: python, python-3.x

**The Challenge**
Given an array of time intervals (start, end) for classroom lectures (possibly overlapping), find the minimum number of rooms required.

For example, given [(30, 75), (0, 50), (60, 150)], you should return 2.

I believe this code has no errors but if you find any, please do let me know. Otherwise, feel free to use this solution if you get stuck

**My Solution**

```
def item_2(element):
    return (element[1]) #Returns second element of tuple for sorting 

classes = [(15,50),(51,53),(54,58),(60,70),(61,63),(65,69),(71,83)]
#classes = [(30, 75), (0, 50), (60, 150), (0, 500), (40, 70)]
classes.sort(key=item_2)

print("The following classes will be needed")
while classes:
    item = classes[0]
    index = 0

    end_time = item[1]
    remaining = classes[1:]
    room_bookings = []
    room_bookings.append(item)
    for next_item in remaining:
        if next_item[0] > end_time:
            room_bookings.append(next_item)
            classes.remove(next_item)
            end_time = next_item[1]
    print(room_bookings)
    classes.remove(item)
```

Comment: Hello EML, given the wording "feel free to use this solution if you get stuck" I'm unsure if you're asking for [Code Review feedback of your code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Am I misunderstanding your post - do you want a code review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clearly show which part of your code is the interesting part, you should define a function:

```
def rooms_required(classes):
    classes = classes[:] # do not modify the argument, make a copy of it
    rooms_bookings = []

    # TODO: insert your code here.

    return len(rooms_bookings)
```

To describe the function in more details, you should add some documentation about the expected data types:

```
from typing import List

def rooms_required(classes: List[(int, int)]) -> int:
    ...
```

This way, you can easily define several test cases:

```
def test_rooms_required():

    # The example from the challenge.
    assert rooms_required([(30, 75), (0, 50), (65, 150)]) == 2

    assert rooms_required([]) == 0

    # This class needs no time at all, therefore it doesn't need a room.
    assert rooms_required([(0, 0)]) == 0

    # Classes that go backwards in time should either be ignored or raise an exception.
    assert rooms_required([(1200, 1100)]) == 0

    # Ensure that rooms_required does not modify the given list,
    # as that would be surprising.
    classes = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (2, 3)]
    assert rooms_required(classes) == 3
    assert rooms_required(classes) == 3
```

Read more about [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) to see how to run these automatic tests.

---

Some more detailed remarks, from top to bottom:

```
def item_2(element):
    return (element[1]) #Returns second element of tuple for sorting
```

Since this challenge is about time spans, it's more helpful to the reader of your code if you call this function `end`, since it returns the *end of a time span*.

```
def end(span):
    return span[1]
```

And since the meaning of `[0]` in the code is not really obvious, you should also define:

```
def start(span):
    return span[0]
```

Then, instead of `span[0]` and `span[1]`, you can write `start(span)` and `end(span)`, which clearly tells a story.

```
classes = [(15,50),(51,53),(54,58),(60,70),(61,63),(65,69),(71,83)]
#classes = [(30, 75), (0, 50), (60, 150), (0, 500), (40, 70)]
```

As I mentioned above, instead of testing only one scenario at a time, you should define a function that does the interesting work, which then allows you to have automatic tests, and several of them at the same time.

```
print("The following classes will be needed")
```

That's wrong. It should be "the following rooms" instead.

```
while classes:
    item = classes[0]
```

The word `item` is a very general term. A better name for this variable is `span`.

```
    index = 0
```

This variable is not used in the rest of the code. You can remove this line.

```
    room_bookings = []
    room_bookings.append(item)
```

You can simplify this into `room_bookings = [span]`.

```
    for next_item in remaining:
        if next_item[0] > end_time:
```

Instead of the `end_time` variable (end time of *what exactly*?), you can write `start(next_span) > end(span)`, which makes the expression look symmetrical and easy to read aloud: *if the next span starts later than the current span ends …*

When you use this pattern, you can remove the `end_time` variable, which will make the code a little shorter.

```
    print(room_bookings)
```

The function that computes the room bookings should not print anything. Printing things is the job of the main program. That's a general rule.